# SASS or LESS for WordPress?

Tags: css, sass, less

I was looking at SASS vs LESS and ended up liking SASS a lot more.

However, I don't really have access to ruby/gems/ all that to get SASS up with everything on my server.

It seems like LESS can just be put in with 2 subsequent links in the header. is this correct?

If so, I'd probably just use LESS - since preprocessing is better than not.

SASS > LESS > CSS - so atleast I'd be a step above if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to run Ruby on the server for SASS, typically you compile it locally before deploying it online.

I prefer SASS, mainly because it's what I used first though, they are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Compass.app](http://compass.handlino.com/) to handle all the techie setup bits on my laptop.

1. I create a project entry;
2. Define what folder to watch for changes;
3. Define where I want the output file to go (typically the root of your theme folder);
4. Enjoy the automatic generation of style.css

Hope this helps.

All the best, Karl

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use this (beta) Wordpress plugin for compiling LESS on shared hosts (and local servers). It uses the reference version of less.js and not a PHP port of it.

[Poor man's less.js](https://github.com/bornemix/pm-less.js)